# FileLeafRef and file extension

Tags: 2010

i'm using CSOM2010 and have following problem.
I try to upload a document.

```
FileCreationInformation fci   = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation();
fci.Content   = bDocument;
fci.Overwrite = true;
fci.Url       = "C:\\temp\test.txt"
File file     = list.RootFolder.Files.Add( fci );
clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Everything works fine.
Now I wanna change the name of the document, f.e.:

```
ListItem listItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
listItem["FileLeafRef"] = "Document";
listItem.Update();
clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

When I execute ExecuteQuery(), the Name (FileLeafRef) will be changed from 'Document' to 'Document.txt'. I need the FileLeafRef at a later time to search the Document with a query, but without the extension. How can I prevent it, or where is the problem?

Comment: The Title is empty.

Comment: file.Name = test.txt, but file.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues dont't has 'Name', but instead FileLeafRef (= Document.txt after second ExecuteQuery() )

Comment: A quick fix I guess would be to trim at the last index of a "."

Comment: You mean, I should trim when I search the file later? But It don't works If I have a document with a Extension. Some file names can have an extension and others not.

Comment: DisplayName is write protected.

Comment: I know that, but for the Search you do not have to write to it, right?

Comment: Yes, but how can I set the Displayname?

Comment: No, "listitem.DisplayName" threw an exception of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException".

Comment: We should chat about this instead, but you do not have enough reputation. Either trim the dot or explore the different other fields of the File to see if you can find, or set, the correct name without extension.

Comment: I wrote that some documents can have an extension, so it's not an option to trim. I have searched all the 56 Fields, but there is no correct name. I'm temporarily testing now with a custom name field and working on the search function. I hope we can find a solution at a later time.